# How is a slave able to paste text from a master?

Tags: virtual-machine

Let's say the master host is Windows 10, running Ubuntu on VMware. I can copy text from the master, then paste it on the slave's terminal.

How does this happen? What's the underlying mechanism behind this?

Comment: It is called Clipboard synchronization. Not sure how exactly VMware handles it though

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you have to install the VMWare Guest tools into the guest OS. These tools can communicate with the host, and the VMWare host has access to the host clipboard.